# Is there a reactive-banana-gtk?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I found the reactive-banana-wx and wonder if there is also a similiar package for gtk as reactive banana should support gtk according to http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana

Comment: I think putting one together based on how reactive-banana-wx works should be pretty easy. You could do it and publish the first reactive-banana-gtk project yourself :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `reactive-banana` library can be used on top of any imperative event-based library via the `AddHandler` type.

However, it is often convenient to write a little glue code that is specific to the library you want to build on. This is what `reactive-banana-wx` does for the `wx` library. I have trouble installing GTK on my Mac, that's why I haven't written a similar glue code package for the `gtk` library. However, other people have used reactive-banana with gtk, for instance John Lato in his [`jaek` project](https://github.com/JohnLato/jaek).