# Alive GUI library with FRP support for Haskell

Tags: animation, haskell, user-interface, frp

Is there any alive Haskell library which implements FRP and could be used to program UI/interactive graphics?

What I expect from such a library:

- Doesn't use any crazy GHC extension, so code could be understood by mortals.
- Not abandoned (had some commits in last 6 mouths and few answered thread in mailing lists).
- Backed by some modern window library (Qt, GTK) and covers fair amount of it functionality.
- Also has drawing and animation support, i.e. let the user to simply define some shapes and effects and bind their parameters to behaviors.

I checked some resources and picture is quite sad.

- Original [Fran](http://conal.net/fran/) and its ancestor [Fruit](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxFruit) family are officially dead.
- [Reactive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive) is an abstract framework and doesn't have bindings to real UI/graphics (did I miss something?).
- [Netwire](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Netwire) also look aimed for general case. Currently it has no documentation covering how to build UI/graphics with it. The only example is a [full application](https://github.com/ocharles/netwire-classics/tree/master/asteroids) not even close to tutorial.
- [Grapefruit](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Grapefruit) looks good, but it had last [commits](http://darcs.grapefruit-project.org/monolithic/0.1/) in December 2013 and the [mailing list](http://projects.haskell.org/pipermail/grapefruit/2014-July/thread.html) full of spam. I consider it abandoned.
- [Yampa](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yampa) has not documentation at all, and the [mailing list](http://mailman.cs.yale.edu/pipermail/yampa-users/) is silent since November 2013.

Comment: [There are several backends for reactive.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=reactive)

Comment: [I think there's just one...](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/reactive)

Comment: Sodium has a Scala port, so that is an alternative, combine it with JavaFX and you have a powerful FRP system. ELM is Haskell like, has all the things you need. Here is also this: http://weblog.luite.com/wordpress/

Comment: I see this question still receives some vote-ups. Please vote for reopen if you find it useful. I agree that asking recommendations for a tool generally aren't helpful for others. But here I ask whether a *class* of tools meeting specific criteria exists. And obviously there are more people looking for an answer.

Answer (score 7):

[Reactive Banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) has been updated relatively regularly, has bindings to SDL, some [decent examples](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples), a [tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FRP_explanation_using_reactive-banana) and a relatively small but decently commented [API reference](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana).

There's also a [backend to wx](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-wx), and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265910/is-there-a-reactive-banana-gtk) about using it with GtK.

The maintainer, [Heinrich Apfelmus, is on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403805/heinrich-apfelmus), and often answers questions on the [reactive-banana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-banana) tag.

Does this suit your needs?

Comment: I would like to add that `reactive-banana` is not a GUI library per se, but a general FRP library with bindings to different GUI libraries. I am currently working on a more tightly integrated GUI+FRP library, [threepenny-gui](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Threepenny-gui).

Answer (score 2):

GUI programming is the major use case of [reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) I believe.